# MySQL Merge Two Tables with Similar Data Union/Join?

Tags: mysql, join, merge, union

So, I have two tables filled with for the most part very similar data, for example, a row in each table may have the same first name, last name, and address, but have a different phone number or email address based on the most recently available data which was updated in a separate excel worksheet (out of my hands, my job is just to merge this data into our latest database which they plan to use from here on out, not the excel sheet). I just need a good way to merge these tables with the same column names without doing it manually (about 24,000+) records.

Here is the Create Table Syntax for both tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `UsersUpdated` (
`FULLNME` longtext,
`LSTNME` varchar(23) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`FSTNME` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`MID` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`SUFF` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`STAT` varchar(2) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`PTY` varchar(3) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`PH` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`ALTPH` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`DOB` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`REGDTE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`ADDR` text,
`ST` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`STNME` varchar(19) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`APT` varchar(7) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`TWN` varchar(6) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`ZIP` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`W` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`d` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`G17` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`P17` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`G16` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`P16` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`G15` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`P15` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`G14` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`P14` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`SIGN` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`SUPP` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`NOTES` longtext,
`LTR` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`REGISTERED` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `Users` (
`FULLNME` longtext,
`LSTNME` varchar(23) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`FSTNME` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`MID` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`SUFF` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`STAT` varchar(2) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`PTY` varchar(3) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`PH` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`ALTPH` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`DOB` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`REGDTE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`ADDR` text,
`ST` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`STNME` varchar(19) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`APT` varchar(7) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`TWN` varchar(6) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`ZIP` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`W` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`d` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`G17` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`P17` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`G16` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`P16` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`G15` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`P15` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`G14` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`P14` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`SIGN` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`SUPP` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`NOTES` longtext,
`LTR` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`REGISTERED` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

As you can see, they are basically the same exact tables, I just need to merge them correctly.

Comment: Well if you can't be confident about which values are going to match it's going to be unreliable. You really should define precisely how you'd like this merging operation to work.

Comment: @shawnt00 I realize that, but is there anyway I can just use the main table as the default and just overwrite all its content with anything in the updated table? That's honestly all that matters. Do I have to run multiple update statements?

Comment: What is the column or columns that uniquely identify a user in both tables?

Comment: I'm a fan of sentences

Comment: Any time you find yourself with enumerated columns alarm bells should start ringing

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is helpful.

```
update Users
set ADDR = (
    select ADDR from UsersUpdated uu
    where uu.FULLNME = Users.FULLNME and uu.DOB = Users.DOB
),  STNME = (
    select STNME from UsersUpdated uu
    where uu.FULLNME = Users.FULLNME and uu.DOB = Users.DOB
) ...
;
```

You can add all the columns to a single update. Depending on the size of the database it might just be as easy to do them individually.

Many platforms allow for a `from` clause with `update` that permits a join and a shorter query but it can be problematic. This way you will get errors if any of the subqueries don't return just a single value.

Comment: So essentially, I'd have to run that on every column to be sure?

Answer (score 0):

I would modify the `Users` table to add a UNIQUE key on the fields that should be the same (presumably FSTNME, LSTNME and ADDR from your description but perhaps you might use some other columns e.g. DOB as suggested by @shawnt00), then `INSERT` the data from `UsersUpdated` into `Users` using an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause to copy updated data into `Users` where the user already exists in that table. This query will also work when there are users in `UsersUpdated` who are not already in `Users`. So,

```
ALTER TABLE Users ADD UNIQUE KEY NameAddr (FSTNME, LSTNME, ADDR);
INSERT INTO Users
   SELECT * FROM UsersUpdated
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      FULLNME=VALUES(FULLNME),
      LSTNME=VALUES(LSTNME),
      FSTNME=VALUKES(FSTNME),
      ...
      LTR=VALUES(LTR),
      REGISTERED=VALUES(REGISTERED);
```